# TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function [React-native]

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

Antes que nada muy buenas, es la primera vez que realizo una pregunta en **Stack**, espero poder brindar toda la información que necesiten para poder dar una mano.

Comencé un proyecto **React Native** Pero al implementar `react-native-nodemediaclient` no funciona obtengo el error mencionado en el titulo. Ya revisé muchas publicaciones pero en ninguna encontre la solución: Dejo el código y el `package.json` por si es un tema de la version de **React**, estaba en la **0.64.1** y pase a la **0.62.2** porque decían que esa era la solución, pero nada.

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.62.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-nodemediaclient": "^0.2.17",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.14.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.14.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.64.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
```

App.js

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {
  createStackNavigator,
  createBottomTabNavigator,
} from '@react-navigation/stack';

import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import CameraScreen from './screens/CameraScreen';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator();
const CameraStack = createStackNavigator();

function HomeStackScreen() {
  return (
    <HomeStack.Navigator>
      <HomeStack.Screen
        name="Inicio"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{tabBarLabel: 'Inicio'}}
      />
    </HomeStack.Navigator>
  );
}

function CameraStackScreen() {
  return (
    <CameraStack.Navigator>
      <CameraStack.Screen
        name="Camera"
        component={CameraScreen}
        options={{tabBarLabel: 'WebCam'}}
      />
    </CameraStack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator>
          <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStackScreen} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={CameraStackScreen} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

screens/HomeScreen.js

```
/* eslint-disable react-native/no-inline-styles */
import React from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StatusBar,
  Platform,
  PermissionsAndroid,
} from 'react-native';
import {NodeMediaClient} from 'react-native-nodemediaclient';

const requestCameraPermission = async () => {
  try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple(
      [
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.RECORD_AUDIO,
      ],
      {
        title: 'Lynx WebCam Camera And Microphone Permission',
        message:
          'Lynx WebCam needs access to your camera ' +
          'so you can take awesome pictures.',
        buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
        buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
        buttonPositive: 'OK',
      },
    );
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      console.log('You can use the camera');
    } else {
      console.log('Camera permission denied');
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err);
  }
};

class HomeScreen extends React.Component() {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      requestCameraPermission();
      NodeMediaClient.setLicense(
        'ZjJhNTIzODAtNGU0ZDUzMjEtY24ubm9kZW1lZGlhLmlTaG93Uk4=-syY8+2t7utLZAKLDs1SaD0EOPC9ft3Zq2SncV7gvMg1vnuEGf6QYMDpiSWj0A7xLhbn62BJHJvi1sGLPKgRflHnT6ysuUfQM7W8fgMA75gbqSCMu4vVqssX+yWCeEIbb5uJ/WHYjSvjSOa0W69TwHB5OSxf0bgAMFo8oJjiSCG16CKRuCHeNQBF8KRh+PYuRDnd3pBmnvE8QyWMDpvtEJd1fSYrGLdwgeO8F4gBKoeXyk2/rpEHKDmm/MKAlHli0/mpz8ejlL6ifAw6rB0TqXfpUMuo6vXpx0bjV7G5wxnOMB5pubn91UWrpRoUhPjadOFiket1DmqPsZFiQGnv0iA==',
      );
    } else if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      NodeMediaClient.setLicense(
        'ZjJhNTIzODAtNGU0ZDUzMjEtY24ubm9kZW1lZGlhLmlTaG93Uk4=-CQ2OZOwxN8PmjPnqCO5jINgwytHewwXJgZ4OhYL0Hnh6TDjQJDL/ebvCV34cuN/LPn42+vEbKxVAhqv492V3RmNu2aPKL6+AlYtPNf1eWkFLYa9Q/5GwU22s98fKA6YB5IMQyG30VptasVRctQeIee/lhmGClkvo9Ib+C8rLai6HHzWst/WpfWJeJs9OYgosNcuS+VmydGAy/CkUkT4G2ew80q239GRSJ7g7KREcwgiPrGqPNiDFqtG1T08JD9SXELerQqIp71qaPRMjCDSk26L0Tg22z4/EKcp713bZGs2AnE3ye3RbsLdMfNNUU0j0Qc/PQFNpczkilbHwMDoRaA==',
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          flexDirection: 'column',
          padding: 24,
          backgroundColor: '#333',
        }}>
        <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" backgroundColor="#6a51ae" />
        <Text
          style={{
            color: '#fff',
            fontSize: 48,
            marginTop: 36,
            marginBottom: 36,
          }}>
          iShow
        </Text>
        <Text style={{color: '#fff', fontSize: 18}}>
          Please enter a stream name.
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

screens/CameraScreen.js

```
/* eslint-disable react-native/no-inline-styles */
import React from 'react';
import {NodeCameraView} from 'react-native-nodemediaclient';
import {View, StatusBar} from 'react-native';

class CameraScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'WebCam',
  };

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {flashenable: false};
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.vb.stop();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#333'}}>
        <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" backgroundColor="#6a51ae" />
        <NodeCameraView
          style={{flex: 1}}
          ref={vb => {
            this.vb = vb;
          }}
          outputUrl={'Vemos como se resuelve'}
          camera={{cameraId: 1, cameraFrontMirror: true}}
          audio={{bitrate: 32000, profile: 1, samplerate: 44100}}
          video={{
            preset: 12,
            bitrate: 400000,
            profile: 1,
            fps: 15,
            videoFrontMirror: false,
          }}
          smoothSkinLevel={3}
          autopreview={true}
          onStatus={(code, msg) => {
            console.log('onStatus=' + code + ' msg=' + msg);
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default CameraScreen;
```

Pero al corre esto, instala correctamente la Aplicación de muestra pero me figura el error:

> TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function

Desde ya muchas gracias a todos aquellos que ayuden y cualquier consulta estoy a su entera disposición.

Comment: en que linea sale ese error?

Comment: Hola, no especifica la linea solo informa el error

Comment: Pues la única que se me ocurre es esta línea:
`class HomeScreen extends React.Component() {` esta línea debería ir sin los paréntesis al final de `React.Component`, depronto eso causa extender una clase que no existe y por eso el error de "super"

Comment: Sos un genio, No me deja marcar tu respuesta como la correcta pero eso me soluciono el error... No entiendo como no lo vi, muchas gracias!

Comment: Ahi te la puse como respuesta... me alegra haberte podido ayudar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues la única que se me ocurre es esta línea:

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component() {
```

debería ir sin los paréntesis al final de `React.Component`, depronto eso causa extender una clase que no existe y por eso el error de "super"